# Challenging Sum: compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2n+1}\left(\zeta(3)-H_n^{(3)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How to prove

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2n+1}\left(\zeta(3)-H_n^{(3)}\right)=\frac74\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{279}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac43\ln^3(2)\zeta(2)-7\ln^2(2)\zeta(3)\\+\frac{53}4\ln(2)\zeta(4)-\frac2{15}\ln^5(2)+16\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)$$

where $H_n^{(q)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^q}$ is the generalized harmonic number,  $\operatorname{Li}_a(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k^a}$ is the polylogarithmic function and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

---

This problem was [proposed](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2428050183958432&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater) by Cornel and no solution has been submitted yet. I managed to convert it to a double integral but it seems tough to crack. Here is what I did:

Using the integral representation of the polygamma function:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^a(x)}{1-x}dx=-\psi^{(a)}(n+1)=(-1)^a a!\left(\zeta(a+1)-H_n^{(a+1)}\right)$$

With $a=2$ we have

$$\zeta(3)-H_n^{(3)}=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^2(x)}{1-x}dx\overset{x=y^2}{=}4\int_0^1\frac{y^{2n+1}\ln^2(y)}{1-y^2}dy$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{H_n}{2n+1}$ then sum up we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2n+1}\left(\zeta(3)-H_n^{(3)}\right)=4\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(y)}{1-y^2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^{2n+1}H_n}{2n+1}\right)dy$$

we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^{2n+1}H_n}{2n+1}=-\int_0^y\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}dx$$

which follows from integrating
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}H_n=-\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}$ from $x=0$ to $x=y$.

so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{2n+1}\left(\zeta(3)-H_n^{(3)}\right)=-4\int_0^1\int_0^y\frac{\ln^2(y)\ln(1-x^2)}{(1-y^2)(1-x^2)}dxdy$$

$$=-4\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\int_x^1\frac{\ln^2(y)}{1-y^2}dy\right)dx$$

For the inner integral, *Mathematica* gives

$$\int_x^1\frac{\ln^2(y)}{1-y^2}dy\\=\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\ln(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)+\ln(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\ln^2(x)\tanh^{-1}(x)+\frac74\zeta(3)$$

and the integral turned out very complicated. So any good idea how to approach the harmonic series or the integral?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong but: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%2F4*zeta%282%29*zeta%283%29-279%2F16*zeta%285%29%2B4%2F3*log%282%29%5E3*zeta%282%29-7*log%282%29%5E2*zeta%283%29%2B53%2F4*log%282%29*zeta%284%29-2%2F15*log%282%29%5E5%2Bpolylog%285%2C1%2F2%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+Harmonic%28n%29%2F%282*n%2B1%29*%28zeta%283%29-Harmonic%28n%2C3%29%29%2Cn%3D1%2C100000

Comment: Sorry @FDP your comment is not clear.

Comment: I think the closed-form in the question is wrong but your expression with integrals for the series is right.

Comment: [value of closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%2F4*zeta%282%29*zeta%283%29-279%2F16*zeta%285%29%2B4%2F3*log%282%29%5E3*zeta%282%29-7*log%282%29%5E2*zeta%283%29%2B53%2F4*log%282%29*zeta%284%29-2%2F15*log%282%29%5E5%2Bpolylog%285%2C1%2F2%29)  and [Series](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+Harmonic%28n%29%2F%282*n%2B1%29*%28zeta%283%29-Harmonic%28n%2C3%29%29%2Cn%3D1%2C100000)

Comment: Ah got you.. actually i didn't check the closed form. I will check it.

Comment: Thank you .. its edited now. I forgot coefficient $16$ of the last term.

Comment: It's ok now. I cannot see the original picture in your question from FB.

Comment: what about now ? https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2428050183958432&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater

Comment: I cannot see the picture sorry. Don't worry your closed-form is probably the good one now.

Comment: sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A second solution in large steps by Cornel Ioan Valean**

Let's start with the following useful identity which is easily derived by using recurrence relations and simple rearrangements, manipulations with sums, that is

> Let $n$ be a non-negative integer number. Then, we have
>   $$\int_0^1 x^{2n}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{2}H_{2n}^2-2\log(2) H_{2n}+\frac{1}{2}H_{2n}^{(2)}-\frac{1}{4}H_n^2-\frac{1}{4}H_n^{(2)}+\log (2)H_n+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{2 k+1},$$
>   where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}$ represents the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$.

By multiplying both sides of the identity above by $1/n^3$ and considering the summation from $n=1$ to $\infty$, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_{k}}{2 k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\frac{H_{k}}{2 k+1}=\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{k}}{2 k+1}\left(\zeta(3)-H_k^{(3)}\right)}_{\text{The desired series}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}^2}{n^3}-2\log(2) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}^{(2)}}{n^3}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}$$
$$+\log (2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n}{n^3}+\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\operatorname{Li}_3(x^2)\textrm{d}x,$$

where we see all the series in the right-hand side are easily reducible to known series which may also be found in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

On the other hand, with simple integration by parts, we obtain
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\operatorname{Li}_3(x^2)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta(3)-2\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\textrm{d}x-2\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x}\textrm{d}x,$$
where the last integrals may be found calculated in the paper [The calculation of a harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving the product of harmonic numbers, $H_n H_{2n}^{(2)}$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336378340).

**A note:** The sister of the result above (easy to obtain by recurrence relations and very useful),

> $$\int_0^1 x^{2n-1} \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=2\log(2) H_{2n}-\log(2)H_n+\frac{1}{4}H_n^2+\frac{1}{4}H_n^{(2)}-\frac{1}{2}H_{2n}^2-\frac{1}{2} H_{2n}^{(2)}+\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}-\frac{H_n}{2n}
> $$
>   $$
> -\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{2 k+1}.
> $$

Comment: I really like this approach (+1).

Comment: @AliShather Thanks.

Comment: @AliShadhar I'm curious to ask where you found the integral identity stated in the beginning

Comment: @Math_Day that's Cornel's solution not mine.

Answer (score 2):

**A first solution in large steps by Cornel Ioan Valean**

Using *The Master Theorem of Series* in the article [A master theorem of series and an evaluation of a cubic harmonic series](http://jca.ele-math.com/10-10/A-master-theorem-of-series-and-an-evaluation-of-a-cubic-harmonic-series) or from the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, pages $288$-$289$, where we set $\mathcal{M}(k)=H_{2k}$, $\displaystyle m(k)=H_{2k}-H_{2k-2}=\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k-1}$, we get

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2k}}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{4}\frac{H_n^2}{n}-\log(2)\frac{H_n}{n}+2\log(2)\frac{H_{2n}}{n}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac{4\log(2)}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{2k+1}.$$

Multiplying both sides of the result above by $1/n^2$ and considering the sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$, we have
$$\frac{5}{2}\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta (3)-4\log (2)\zeta(2)+4\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n(2n-1)}-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^3}$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^4}+\zeta(2)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}}{n^2}-\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^3}}_{\text{A tough series}}$$ 
$$=16 \log (2)-16 \log ^2(2)-4\log (2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{4}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{(2 n+1) n^3}-\log (2)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{ H_n}{n^3}$$
$$+2 \log (2)\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{4}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}+\underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{2 n+1}\left(\zeta (3)-H_n^{(3)}\right)}_{\text{The desired series}},$$
where in the calculations we used the folowing result from the paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$](http://researchgate.net/publication/335920055),
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^3}$$
$$=\frac{307}{128}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3}\log ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{8}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{15} \log ^5(2)$$
$$-2 \log (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -2 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
and at the same time we used that by reversing the summation order our desired series is (almost) revealed $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{H_k}{2k+1}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{2 n+1}\left(\zeta (3)-H_n^{(3)}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$

The rest of the series are well-known (or immediately reducible to well-known series), and all of them may also be found calculated in the book,  **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.

**A note**: By using the same procedure, we may calculate the series 
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{2 n+1}\left(\zeta (2)-H_n^{(2)}\right),$$
or other versions if we know the resulting series after applying this strategy.

Comment: (+1) for the nice work.